# Boost Serialization Mysterious negative integral constant Warning

Tags: c++, serialization, boost

I have the following test code (completely compilable):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <boost/archive/text_oarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/archive/text_iarchive.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/array.hpp>
#include <boost/serialization/map.hpp>
typedef unsigned int addressvalue_t;
using namespace std;
class base {
public:
  virtual int get()=0;
};
class sub1:public base {
  int a,b;
  std::shared_ptr<vector<addressvalue_t>> addressListPtr;
  std::shared_ptr<vector<unsigned char>> commonData;
public:
  sub1(int a,int b):a(a),b(b){}
  virtual int get() {
    return a*b*10;
  }
   friend class boost::serialization::access;
  template<class Archive>
  void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
  {
      ar & a;
      ar & b;
      ar & addressListPtr;
      ar & commonData;
  }
  void serializeMe() {
    std::ofstream ofs("filename");
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
    oa << *this;

  }
};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
  sub1 * b;
  b=new sub1(22,33);
#if 0  
  std::ofstream ofs("filename");
  boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ofs);
  oa << *b;
#else
  b->serializeMe();
#endif
  return 0;
}
```

When i compiled it using VC++2010 and boost 1.68. The compilation succeeded but yielded the following warning mysteriously:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: cpptest, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  cpptest.cpp
1>c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\mpl\print.hpp(55): warning C4308: negative integral constant converted to unsigned type
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\static_warning.hpp(88) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::mpl::print<T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=boost::serialization::BOOST_SERIALIZATION_STATIC_WARNING_LINE<137>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\check.hpp(137) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::serialization::static_warning_test<B,L>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              B=false,
1>              L=137
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(460) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::check_pointer_level<T>(void)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=std::vector<unsigned int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(480) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_pointer_type<Archive>::save<T>(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::vector<unsigned int>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(539) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke<const T>(Archive &,const TPtr)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=const std::vector<unsigned int> *,
1>              TPtr=const std::vector<unsigned int> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\common_oarchive.hpp(71) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::save<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=const std::vector<unsigned int> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\basic_text_oarchive.hpp(83) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<T>(T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=const std::vector<unsigned int> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\interface_oarchive.hpp(70) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<const T>(T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=const std::vector<unsigned int> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\nvp.hpp(67) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator <<<T>(const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=const std::vector<unsigned int> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\access.hpp(91) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::nvp<T>::save<Archive>(Archive &,const unsigned int) const' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=const std::vector<unsigned int> *,
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\split_member.hpp(43) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::access::member_save<Archive,const T>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\split_member.hpp(42) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::serialization::detail::member_saver<Archive,T>::invoke(Archive &,const T &,const unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\split_member.hpp(69) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::serialization::detail::member_saver<Archive,T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\nvp.hpp(76) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::split_member<Archive,boost::serialization::nvp<T>>(Archive &,boost::serialization::nvp<T> &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=const std::vector<unsigned int> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\access.hpp(116) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::nvp<T>::serialize<Archive>(Archive &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              T=const std::vector<unsigned int> *,
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\serialization.hpp(68) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::access::serialize<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\serialization.hpp(126) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::serialize<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(250) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::serialize_adl<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(315) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::save_only::invoke<T>(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(539) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke<const T>(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\common_oarchive.hpp(71) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::save<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\basic_text_oarchive.hpp(83) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<T>(T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\interface_oarchive.hpp(70) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<const T>(T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=boost::serialization::nvp<const std::vector<unsigned int> *>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\shared_ptr.hpp(236) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator <<<boost::serialization::nvp<T>>(const boost::serialization::nvp<T> &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=const std::vector<unsigned int> *
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\split_free.hpp(45) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::save<Archive,std::vector<_Ty>>(Archive &,const std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<_Ty>> &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              _Ty=unsigned int
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\split_free.hpp(41) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::serialization::free_saver<Archive,T>::invoke(Archive &,const T &,const unsigned int)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\split_free.hpp(74) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::serialization::free_saver<Archive,T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\shared_ptr.hpp(273) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::split_free<Archive,std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              _Ty=std::vector<unsigned int>,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\serialization.hpp(126) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::serialize<Archive,std::vector<_Ty>>(Archive &,std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<_Ty>> &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              _Ty=unsigned int
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(157) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::serialize_adl<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(149) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::archive::detail::oserializer<Archive,T>::save_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive &,const void *) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(263) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::archive::detail::oserializer<Archive,T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(315) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::save_standard::invoke<T>(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(539) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke<const T>(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\common_oarchive.hpp(71) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::save<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\basic_text_oarchive.hpp(83) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<T>(T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\interface_oarchive.hpp(70) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<const T>(T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\interface_oarchive.hpp(77) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator <<<T>(const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\work\cpptest\cpptest\cpptest.cpp(43) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator &<std::tr1::shared_ptr<_Ty>>(const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              _Ty=std::vector<unsigned int>,
1>              T=std::tr1::shared_ptr<std::vector<unsigned int>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\access.hpp(116) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void sub1::serialize<Archive>(Archive &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\serialization.hpp(68) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::access::serialize<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\serialization\serialization.hpp(126) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::serialize<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(157) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::serialization::serialize_adl<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &,const unsigned int)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(149) : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::archive::detail::oserializer<Archive,T>::save_object_data(boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive &,const void *) const'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(263) : see reference to class template instantiation 'boost::archive::detail::oserializer<Archive,T>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(315) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::save_standard::invoke<T>(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\oserializer.hpp(539) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::save_non_pointer_type<Archive>::invoke<const T>(Archive &,const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\common_oarchive.hpp(71) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::save<Archive,T>(Archive &,T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\basic_text_oarchive.hpp(83) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::detail::common_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<T>(T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\bin\boost_1_68_0\boost\archive\detail\interface_oarchive.hpp(70) : see reference to function template instantiation 'void boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<Archive>::save_override<const T>(T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>          c:\work\cpptest\cpptest\cpptest.cpp(49) : see reference to function template instantiation 'Archive &boost::archive::detail::interface_oarchive<Archive>::operator <<<sub1>(const T &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              Archive=boost::archive::text_oarchive,
1>              T=sub1
1>          ]
1>     Creating library c:\work\cpptest\Debug\cpptest.lib and object c:\work\cpptest\Debug\cpptest.exp
1>  cpptest.vcxproj -> c:\work\cpptest\Debug\cpptest.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

After some trial and error, I found that if i comment out the following 2 members in my `serialize` function, the warning disappears:

```
  //ar & addressListPtr;
  //ar & commonData;
```

Why was there such a warning and what's wrong with my code?

Also, my base class only consists of pure virtual function declarations and has no member variables, there is no need to serialize it in any way. All serialization is done in 1 of the derived classes.  So I decided to use a `serializeMe()` member function, is it a bad style?

Edit:
Some more information:

```
line 57 of ...\boost\mpl\print.hpp

template <class T>
struct print
    : mpl::identity<T>
#if defined(__MWERKS__)
    , aux::print_base
#endif 
{
#if defined(__clang__)
# pragma clang diagnostic push
# pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wc++11-extensions"
    const int m_x = 1 / (sizeof(T) - sizeof(T));
# pragma clang diagnostic pop
#elif defined(BOOST_MSVC)
    enum { n = sizeof(T) + -1 };//<---------line 57
#elif defined(__MWERKS__)
    void f(int);
#else 
    enum {
        n =
# if defined(__EDG_VERSION__)
           aux::dependent_unsigned<T>::value > -1
# else 
           sizeof(T) > -1
# endif 
        };
#endif 
};
```

line 137 of check.hpp

```
    // Address the following when serializing to a pointer:

    // a) This type doesn't save class information in the
    // archive. That is, the serialization trait implementation
    // level <= object_serializable.
    // b) Tracking for this type is set to "track selectively"

    // in this case, indication that an object is tracked is
    // not stored in the archive itself - see level == object_serializable
    // but rather the existence of the operation ar >> T * is used to 
    // infer that an object of this type should be tracked.  So, if
    // you save via a pointer but don't load via a pointer the operation
    // will fail on load without given any valid reason for the failure.

    // So if your program traps here, consider changing the 
    // tracking or implementation level traits - or not
    // serializing via a pointer.
    BOOST_STATIC_WARNING(typex::value); //<---------line137
}
```

Comment: for print.hpp / check.hpp see my edits

Comment: I guess the comment in check.hpp is what we need to understand. But I have no idea what it is about!